# How to correctly use the linker /SOURCELINK option with c++

Tags: .net, msbuild, sourcelink

We are using SourceLink with c# projects and it is working just fine.
When we try to use it on C++ projects the /SOURCELINK option in the linker seems to be ignored as there is no relevant metadata in the produced PDB

I am using this MSBuild:

```
 msbuild /version
 Enterprise
 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.168+ga8fba1ebd7 for .NET Framework
 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

 15.8.168.64424
```

The Linker option is documented here: [/SOURCELINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/sourcelink?view=vs-2017)

We are using it like this

```
/SOURCELINK:"C:\Projects\SourceLinkTest\sourcelink.json"
```

with a hand crafted JSON file (because our Stash is still on v4.5.2)

```
{"documents":
{"C:\\Projects\SourceLinkTest\\*":
    "https://stash.mycompany.com/projects/EDMPTF/repos/sourcelink/browse/*?at=ae281edb41c2da2a9375a63d8be9dd3ca00660fd&raw"
}
}
```

the MSBuild Link step looks like this:

```
Link:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Projects\SourceLinkTest\Debug\SourceLi  nkTest.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='fa  lse'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG:FASTLINK /PDB:"C:\Projects\SourceLinkTest\Debug\SourceLinkTest.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:\Projects\SourceLinkTest\Debug\SourceLinkTest.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SOURCELINK:"C:\Projects\SourceLinkTest\sourcelink.json" Debug\SourceLinkTest.res        
Debug\SourceLinkTest.obj                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Debug\stdafx.obj                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
SourceLinkTest.vcxproj -> 
C:\Projects\SourceLinkTest\Debug\SourceLinkTest.exe
```

We use Jetbrains dotPeek to check the PDB contents as the SourceLink V3 tool can only analyse portable PDBs

Comment: A commit to support C++ in vsxproj files was merged 9 days ago. https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/issues/161 & the latest build on nuget is 2 months old.

Comment: @CameronTaggart I think It's not sourcelink package issue, but the link - it takes the /sourcelink argument, but does not add entry into pdb

Comment: Sure, but it links to this section which I think is how he solved it: https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/pull/165/files#diff-106520b7bd95111d8dcfa592ae18d672R59

Comment: These changes seem to be for the target that build the json, we are supplying a hand-crafted json so I am not sure how this applies. Could be I am missing something fundamental here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After conversation with Microsoft developers it turns-out this is a bug. Partial fix is in VS2017 15.9.7. Full fix is in VS2019.